# Updating text on an existing docx

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

My project creates a simple docx by reading data from an api and uploads it to dropbox where some user may read and make comments to the document. At some point the data may change so I need to update the same in the docx. I can download the docx from dropbox and read but

1) **How do I update the data (some text) in an existing document which has no placeholder text and also preserve the comments?**

2) **I am pretty new to docx4j and have been following their examples to get to this point would someone please give me some insight into content control**

The code below is how I'm creating the docx with change tracking enabled

```
try {
        wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText(
                "Heading3",
                "User information");

        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText(
                "First Name : " + firstName );
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText(
                "Last Name : " + lastName );
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText(
                "Email : " + emailId );
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText(
                "Phone number : " + phoneNum );
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText(
                "Company name : " + companyName );
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText(
                "Heading3", "Static content");
        wordMLPackage
                .getMainDocumentPart()
                .addParagraphOfText(
                        "This section is to demonstrate static text in the generated document.");



        Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
        // if directory exists?
        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            try {
                Files.createDirectories(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // fail to create directory
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Enable change tracking
        enableDocxChangeTracking(wordMLPackage);
        // Now save it
        wordMLPackage
                .save(new java.io.File(filePath
                        + System.getProperty("file.separator") + fileName
                        + ".docx"));

    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367794/how-to-append-data-in-docx-file-using-docx4j

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not actually looking merge two documents, my scenario is more of a search and replace operation, except that the method will not know what string to search for. The output document will be similar to a filled out form with labels and text. I'd like to have id attributes in the runs that contain the text to be replaced which can be referenced. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

- You can mark parts with bookmarks and should be able to replace/insert text as shown [here](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/BookmarksReplaceWithText.java)
- You may use text-placeholders and therefore [TextUtils](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/TextUtils.java) as mentioned [here](https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/find-replace-text-t225.html). Though this is not applicable, once placeholders have been replaced with text
- You can mark specific document-parts with [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157891.aspx)-Elements as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj889465.aspx). These elements can be enriched with a title (in XML: 'ali and/or tag for addressing - also these have an unique id in the referring document.xml. With docx4j you can address these via JAXB using [MainDocumentPart](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/MainDocumentPart.java)#getJAXBNodesViaXPath

I applied the last option in my current project, where we generate *.docx by merging several files and inserting information into such CC-elements. We did that to mark parts for specific text insertion, while keeping them updatable.

Cheers, Dominik